# tidy_parse_file(): Could not set encoding 'UTF-8'

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to change a html file to xhtml. I'm using tidy_parse_file(), but my source is in Chinese.
If I do not specify the encoding in tidy_parse_file, all the Chinese character get converted to HTML ESCAPE like “ç·&#180.
But when I try to specify the encoding, I get this warning:
Warning: tidy_parse_file(): Could not set encoding 'UTF-8'

What went wrong?

```
$tidy = tidy_parse_file("http://courseap.itc.ntnu.edu.tw/acadmOpenCourse/SyllabusTopCtrl?course_code=ITU0008&dept_code=HU71", array("numeric-entities" => true, "output-xhtml" => true), "UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `utf8` rather than `UTF-8`.

---

#### [PHP: tidy::parseFile - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.parsefile.php):

> **encoding**
>
> > The **encoding** parameter sets the encoding for input/output documents. The possible values for encoding are: *ascii, latin0, latin1, raw, utf8, iso2022, mac, win1252, ibm858, utf16, utf16le, utf16be, big5,* and *shiftjis*.